# How do I narrow MySQL fulltext search results?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MySQL fulltext search engine and I want to allow the user to filter results by adding a range of years for the results. I have a column called `year` that has years ranging from 1999 to 2011. How do I alter my `mysql_query` to reflect this? The variable `$fyear` is the year that the user wanted to begin at (lower end), and `$tyear` is the year to end at (higher end).

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("database");

$var = @$_GET['q'];
$fyear = @$_GET['from_year'];
$tyear = @$_GET['to_year'];

if (isset($var)) {
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, MATCH(subj_name, course_name) AGAINST ('$var') 
AS score from table1 WHERE MATCH (subj_name, course_name) AGAINST('$var') 
ORDER BY score desc");
}
```

NOTE: The column `year` is an integer field

Comment: Is your year an integer or a string field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the operator [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, MATCH(subj_name, course_name) AGAINST ('$var') AS 
score from table1 WHERE year BETWEEN '$fyear' AND '$tyear' MATCH (subj_name, course_name) AGAINST('$var') ORDER
BY score desc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with full text search, but can't you just add conditions to your query like this?

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, MATCH(subj_name, course_name) AGAINST ('$var') AS 
score from table1 WHERE year BETWEEN $fyear AND $tyear AND MATCH (subj_name, course_name)   AGAINST('$var') ORDER BY score desc");
```